# CSS Confused with 100%. Need three blocks to stick to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm using an `<ul>` block with three items (`<li>`) to structure a navigation area.

The `<ul>` block does not have a fixed width. It fits its parent.
I need all `<li>`s to be horizontally aligned, one next to each other inside.
There are three `<li>`s in total.
The last two have fixed widths.
First one should take as much as space as possible.

How can I structure this? When I am using 100% for the width of first `<li>`, it takes all the space.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple code example should be added to your question.

Comment: give your second and third <li> a class and give them specific fixed widths in the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact, it's very simple. You kind anwsered your own question.

http://jsfiddle.net/UYW85/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>@Lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    <li class="n2">number 2</li>
    <li class="n3">number 3</li>    
<ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { width:100%; height:100px; }
ul > li { float:left; background-color:#AAA; }
.n2 { width:100px; background-color:#CCC;}
.n3 { width:100px; background-color:#CCC;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your exact question, but just as a resource - have you checked out jQuery Nested?

http://suprb.com/apps/nested/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table` for `UL` and `display: table-cell` for `LI`.